# Why is there a pip package in pip?

Tags: python, pypi

So I was looking through PyPI and I found this: https://pypi.org/project/pip/
What is the reason for this? Why does this exist, and why would it be useful?? Isnt it kinda recursive in a way?

Comment: Also, `pip` is not the only way to retrieve packages from PyPi.

Answer (score 1):

`pip` can update itself to a newer version and has a bootstrapper called `get-pip.py` to install it for the first time.  Since recent Python versions have it pre-installed, upgrading is usually all that is needed to get the latest version of `pip`.

See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is there a pip package in pip?

I think you're conflating the following two tools:

- PyPI (https://pypi.org) is a repository for hosting Python packages
- pip (https://pypi.org/p/pip) is an installer that downloads packages from PyPI